# Html collapsible not expanding on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

My code seems fine (or maybe it's not), when I try it on online platforms it seems to work but it doesn't work when I run it locally. For example, when I put in the exact code in w3school's try it in editor there seems to be no problem.

This is the javascript file I'm using:
"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"

When I tried looking online I keep getting answers saying that you need a jquery file which I'm sure I have.

Help is very much appreciated.

Edit: Earlier on in my code I used "content2" instead of "content". That was a mistake, I was just messing around with my code and forgot to change it back. It still doesn't work with "content".

```html
<div class="prtbox">
  <img src="graphics/tmp/xx1.png" class="partnerimg">
  <div class="partnerdesc">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="prtbox">
  <img src="graphics/tmp/xx2.png" class="partnerimg">
  <div class="partnerdesc">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="prtbox">
  <img src="graphics/tmp/xx3.png"class="partnerimg">
  <div class="partnerdesc">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  </div>
  </div>
```

```css
.partnerimg{
  width: 250px;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.prtbox{
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  width: 33%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.partnerdesc{
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("partnerimg");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

EDIT: As the problem seems to lie with code on my side that i have not shown here, i will list my .html code here. I am only using a html and css file, and my entire css file has been shown

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>

<script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("partnerimg");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = this.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
</script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index_styles2.css">
  </head>

<body>


  <div class="prtbox">
  <img src="graphics/tmp/ca.png" class="partnerimg">
  <div class="partnerdesc">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="prtbox">
  <img src="graphics/logob.eps" class="partnerimg">
  <div class="partnerdesc">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no using jQuery , so you dont need jQuery . replace `content2` to `this` will work for me

Comment: it still doesnt work. It works on w3schools editor and stackoverflow editor but not locally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try placing your script toward the bottom of your HTML document, at least after the elements it uses. It's probably running before the DOM has finished loading so the elements haven't been created yet causing it to throw an error.

Comment: yeah that was the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try as below:

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("partnerimg");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = this.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.partnerimg{
  width: 250px;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.prtbox{
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  width: 33%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.partnerdesc{
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="prtbox">
  <img src="graphics/tmp/xx1.png" class="partnerimg">
  <div class="partnerdesc">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="prtbox">
  <img src="graphics/tmp/xx2.png" class="partnerimg">
  <div class="partnerdesc">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="prtbox">
  <img src="graphics/tmp/xx3.png"class="partnerimg">
  <div class="partnerdesc">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  </div>
  </div>
```

I have try below code in local system and its working fine. Check it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
<style>
    .partnerimg {
        width: 250px;
        padding-bottom: 2%;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .prtbox {
        padding-bottom: 30px;
        width: 33%;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .partnerdesc {
        padding: 0 18px;
        background-color: white;
        max-height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="prtbox">
       <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100X100/000/fff" class="partnerimg">
         <div class="partnerdesc">
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
        dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
</div>

<div class="prtbox">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100X100/000/fff" class="partnerimg">
    <div class="partnerdesc">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
        dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
</div>

<div class="prtbox">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100X100/000/fff" class="partnerimg">
    <div class="partnerdesc">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
        dolore magna aliqua.
      </div>
   </div>
 </body>
 <script>
   var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("partnerimg");
   var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
    coll[i].addEventListener("click", function () {

        var content = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (content.style.maxHeight) {
            content.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
            content.style.maxHeight = this.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I can't see the use of jQuery.

Comment: this is the problem im facing. I used the exact same code, it works right here, but for some reason it does not work when i open the page from my own computer. Thanks for your help though.

Does it help if i say im writing the javascript in the html page through <script></script> and not through a separate file

Comment: @kwkwkw if it works here but not on your computer there is something else going on with the code on your computer that you have not presented to us here. Do you get console errors, if so what are they

Comment: @JonP the problem definitely seems to lie on my side of the code which i have not shown, I have displayed my html code above.

Comment: Which type of error you are getting in the console?

Comment: I also getting the error related to image not found. We can set other dummy images over there. My code is working in local system as well

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, jquery is not required over here. The other issue is, this code will not work in online editors also, as the element content2, whose height you are trying to access is not defined. Changing it to the following will also work for you -

```
content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
```

Comment: content2 was my mistake as i was messing around with the code. It still doesn't work with content

Comment: where exactly are you placing the javascript code in your file? I mean towards the end of the file, or before the html content